# Dividing an ellipse into equal area

Tags: geometry

[image]Can an ellipse be divided into sectors of equal area? Is there any generalized formula to do so? The total area of the ellipse $A$ has to be divided into $n$ equal sectors such that $A=A_1+A_2+ ⋯+A_n$ given its semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$. Any solution or resources will be of great help?

Comment: Reminds me of that one Kepler's law: A planet in an elliptic orbit sweeps out equal areas in equal times.

Comment: What is the origin of the sectors? One of the foci, or the center of the ellipse?

Comment: I think that this is (potentially) an interesting question, but I feel like I am forced to vote to put it on hold as "lacking context."  If you were to edit your question to to provide an answer to the issue raised by Arthur, I would be more than willing to retract that vote.  It might also be worthwhile to spend some time thinking about Kepler's law; a unit speed parameterization of the ellipse would likely give the right answer.

Comment: @Arthur: The origin of the sectors lies at the center of the ellipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that any ellipse can be obtained by affinity from a circle and that the affinity preserves the ratio between the areas.

Thus we can consider the division into sectors of equal area for a circle and then the corresponding affine transformation to the ellipse.

[image]

Notably. as an example, let consider the affinity by $X=ax$ and $Y=by$ such that

$$x^2+y^2=1 \to \frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1$$

with reference to the first quadrant, the equations for the lines dividing the circle into $n$ sectors of equal area $A=\frac{\pi}{4n}$ are

$$y=(\tan \theta_k)\cdot x, \quad \theta_k=\frac{k\pi}{2n},\quad k=1,...,n-1$$

the equations for the lines dividing the ellipse into $n$ sectors of equal area $A=\frac{\pi ab}{4n}$ are

$$Y=\frac b a (\tan \theta_k)\cdot X, \quad \theta_k=\frac{k\pi}{2n},\quad k=1,...,n-1$$

Comment: Thanks for the information and it worked.

Comment: Well done! You are welcome! Bye

Comment: I have one more question. Does this solution can also be scaled to superellipse. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797052/dividing-concentric-super-ellipses-to-equal-area-slices/2797062#2797062

Comment: Yes of course, I’m going to add also something on that if you loke.

Comment: That was so neat !   Works when first sector radius does not coincide with x-axis?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, it works for any configuration!

Comment: @gimusi yes please, it would be of great help.

Comment: @pretty Sorry now i can't but I will give a look later! Bye

Comment: Comment was.. as  the sketch did not contain ellipses with inclined axes.