# Dividing concentric super ellipses to equal area slices

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[image]How the concentric super ellipses as shown in the figure can be divided into parts containing equal area such that the total area of the superellipse *A* = *A*1 + *A*2 + ... *A*n where *n* = 60 in the shown figure given its semi-major axis *a* and semi-minor axis *b*. The origin of the sectors lies at the center of the superellipse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ah sorry you are looking for superellipse! then of course the trick used earlier doesn't work here

Comment: @gimusi The explanation for the ellipse is precise and clear but I am searching an apt solution for super ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

Solve the problem for concentric circles in the unit circle centered at the origin. Then stretch the $x$-axis by $a$ and the $y$-axis by $b$ to turn the circles into ellipses. All the areas will be scaled by the same stretch factor.

This is essentially the same question you asked here:  [Dividing an ellipse into equal area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796214/dividing-an-ellipse-into-equal-area)

Comment: @ Ethan: sorry for not mentioning as superellipse and have edited the question appropriately.

Comment: @pretty Thanks for accepting the answer, but is it an answer? Uniform stretching won't make a superellipse, variable stretching might, but wouldn't do the areas uniformly.

Comment: @EthanThe answer holds for ellipse and it helped me but not for superellipse. I am still waiting if someone could answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following the same idea presented here [Dividing an ellipse into equal area](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796214/505767), it suffices consider the affinity by $X=ax$ and $Y=by$ such that

$$x^2+y^2=1 \to \frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1$$

and divide the unit circle in 60 equals parts by the lines

- $y=0$
- $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}x$
- $y=\pm{\sqrt 3}x$
- $x=0$

and by the circles

- $x^2+y^2=\frac{\sqrt 5}5$
- $x^2+y^2=\frac{\sqrt {10}}5$
- $x^2+y^2=\frac{\sqrt {15}}5$
- $x^2+y^2=\frac{2\sqrt {5}}5$

[image]

thus the equations for the lines and ellipses dividing the main ellipse into $60$ sectors of equal area $A=\frac{\pi ab}{60}$ are

- $Y=0$
- $Y=\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\frac b a X$
- $y=\pm{\sqrt 3}\frac b a X$
- $X=0$

for the lines and

- $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=\frac{\sqrt 5}5$
- $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=\frac{\sqrt {10}}5$
- $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=\frac{\sqrt {15}}5$
- $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=\frac{2\sqrt {5}}5$